# Dynamic file creation(naming)

Tags: python

Is it possible to do the following in python?

```
i=1
    while True: 
      w = open("POSCAR_i","w")
      i=i+1
      if i<10:
        break
```

So Basically, it should create `POSCAR_1` through `POSCAR_10`.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to execute this code? What results do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is much more pythonic (and all around better) to use a for loop:

```
for idx in range(1,11):
    f = open("POSCAR_%d" % idx, "w")
    f.close()
```

You can also use the format() method, which is now officially preferred, although the % operator is still much more common in the wild.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your `break` statement was executed on the first iteration.
The `i` variable is indeed less than 10 - so the loop terminates.

What you would need to do is something like this:

```
i = 1
while True:
    w = open("POSCAR_%d" % i, "w")
    w.close()
    i += 1
    if i == 10:
        break
```

Don't forget to close the file object once you have finished with it (which in this case is immediately).

---

You could also just put the termination condition in the loop's definition:

```
i = 1
while i <= 10:
    w = open("POSCAR_%d" % i, "w")
    w.close()
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to pass in i as a variable:

```
w = open("POSCAR_{}".format(i),"w")
```

If you wanted 1 - 10, a for loop would do the same.

```
for i in range(1,11):
    w = open("POSCAR_{}".format(i),"w")
```

But `w` will  be reassigned each time.

You need to use `if i==10` or your loop will end straight away as `i` is `< 10` initially

You can use `i <=10` as the condition and remove the if statement:

```
i=1
while i <= 10:
   with open("POSCAR_{}".format(i),"w") as w: # with will close your files automatically
       i+=1
```

Comment: you could have just commented, it was obviously a typo

Comment: I don't think he was looking for a re-write just a way to make it work - you're solution logically is correct but syntactically wrong

Comment: @gkusner, how is it a rewrite and how syntactically wrong?

Comment: Well now that you have changed it the syntax is correct

Answer (score 1):

Almost correct

```
i=1
while True: 
  w = open("POSCAR_%d" % i,"w")
  i=i+1
  if i>10:
    break
```

will work

Comment: Nope... did you test this?

Comment: Better :) but this misses the last iteration and doesn't create `POSCAR_10`

Comment: Darn off by one errors - well that is easy to fix - but i think your answer is better while still keeping the feel of the original code

Answer (score 1):

Basically the answer is no. Here is some information regarding why it is not possible and also some polishing.

There are a couple of problems regarding your code:

1. the line `w = open("POSCAR_i","w")` creates a file with the name of *POSCAT_i*. The `i` is perceived as a part of a string. You should construct such a string via using `w = open("POSCAR_%d" % i, "w")` instead of `w = open("POSCAR_i","w")`.
2. The `if` executes the first time because its condition is met. As in the first iteration, `i = 1`, the condition `i < 10` is met so `break` is executed. Change the `if` condition to `i > 10`.
3. Also it would b a good practice to use `for` loop instead of `while` loop. In this case, you would not an `if` block anymore.
4. It is also a good practice to close the file handle before using it for other purposes. Or an even better practice is using different file handles.

So I would write the code in this way:

```
# Previous codes
.
.
.
Files = [];
for i in range(1,11):
    w = open("POSCAR_%d" % i, "w");
    Files.append(w);
# Rest of the code
.
.
.
for w in Files:
    w.close();
# End of code
```

Enjoy!